# Google Cloud SQL cannot connect to Apache Superset

Tags: google-cloud-sql, apache-superset, postgres15

While trying to connect Apache Superset to Google Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) I get this error:

[image: 5432 The port is closed.]

I also unsuccessfully tried to connect by SQLAlchemy URI string
`postgresql://username:password@host:port/database` as well as
`PostgreSQL+psycopg2://username:password@host:port/database?sslmode=require`;
yielding
`Error: Please check your connection details and database settings, and ensure that your database is accepting connections, then try connecting again.`

What I used:

- Superset: 2.1.0 (installed on Google virtual machine)
- PostgreSQL: 15.2 (Google Cloud SQL)

Can somebody help to understand and solve?

Comment: Also, i tried to connect by public IP ( cloud sql )

Answer (score 2):

Private IP has to be created in cloud SQL to connect to Superset. [Link to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend configuring Superset to connect to the private IP address of your Google Cloud SQL Postgres instance. This has a few main benefits:

- Your postgres database is not reachable from the public internet.
- The database connection will behave like any other posgres database.

First, get the name of the VPC connected to the VMs running your Superset application.

Then, you have two options to configure access to Cloud SQL from your private network:

**Option 1: Use the instance's Private IP Address**

If your Cloud SQL Instance will only be accessed from one VPC, then configure it to

Configure your Cloud SQL instance to attach a private IP address to that VPC following the instructions here [Cloud SQL Configure Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip)

To enable the private IP on an existing instance using the gcloud cli:

```
gcloud beta sql instances patch INSTANCE_ID \
--project=PROJECT_ID \
--network=projects/NETWORK_PROJECT_ID/global/networks/VPC_NETWORK_NAME \
--no-assign-ip \
--enable-google-private-path
```

Then, get the private IP address for your instance from the cloud console,
or by running this command:

```
gcloud beta sql instances describe <INSTANCENAME>
```

Which will produce output that looks like this, including the private ip address for the instance.

```
connectionName: <CONNECTION NAME>
# ...
instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
ipAddresses:
- ipAddress: 10.2.2.2 ### Note: your instance address will be different
  type: PRIVATE
# ...
```

Finally, connect your database using the private IP Address with a connection string like this:

```
postgresql://username:password@10.2.2.2:5432/database
```

**Option 2: Use Private Service Connect**

If your Cloud SQL Instance needs to be reached from multiple applications running on different VPCs, need to configure [Private Service Access](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-services-access)

This is considerably more complex to set up, but has the advantage of being a more flexible way to connect a Cloud SQL instance to multiple VPC networks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of External IP enter the Internal Ip address when it is asking for IP address and in port provide 3306 port it is the default port address